How can I get session information in Zoom Video UI Toolkit?
I'm using the Zoom Video UI Toolkit in my Angular project to set up Zoom meetings. I need to retrieve session information, such as the session ID, when the session starts. I've implemented the session join functionality, but I'm unsure how to access the session details.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
this.sessionContainer = this.document.getElementById('sessionContainer');
    this.config.videoSDKJWT = this.generateSignature(
      environment.zoomSDKKey,
      environment.zoomSDKSecret,
      this.config.sessionName,
      1,
      'session123',
      'user123',
    );

    if (this.sessionContainer) {
      uitoolkit.joinSession(this.sessionContainer, this.config);
    } else {
      console.error('Preview or session container not found');
    }

I tried to fetch data using uitoolkit.onSessionJoined, but I am not getting any session information.
